# Solving a weighted XOR-SAT problem

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, solver, binary-variable, or-tools

I want to solve a variant of the [weighted XOR-SAT problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43956/is-weighted-xor-sat-np-hard). Concretely,

> Given $n$ boolean variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ each of which is assigned a non-negative cost $c_1,\ldots,c_n\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and a boolean function $f$ on these variables given in the form $$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\bigwedge_{i=1}^k\bigoplus_{j=1}^{l_i}x_{r_{ij}}$$ ($\oplus$ denoting XOR) with $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, integers $1\leq l_i\leq n$ and $1\leq r_{i1}<\cdots<r_{il_i}\leq n$ for all $i=1,\ldots,k$, $j=1,\ldots,l_i$, the problem is to find an assignment of minimum cost for $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ that satisfies $f$, if such an assignment exists. The cost of an assignment is simply given by $$\sum_{\substack{i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\\x_i\,\text{true}}}c_i.$$

This problem is essentially XOR-SAT with a linear objective.
The difference between my formulation and the one in the linked question above is that $c_i$ can take values in $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$.

How do I solve it with an off-the-shelf solver, like OR-Tools or Gurobi? By "solve it", I mean finding a solution that is good enough in a reasonable amount of time, not finding the optimal solution exactly. This problem is NP-complete after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a nonnegative integer variable $y_i$ and minimize $\sum_j c_j x_j$ subject to $Ax=2y+1$, where $Ax=1$ is the system of equality constraints defined in the linked question.  The role of $y$ is to convert an equality in $\mathbb{F}_2$ to an equality in $\mathbb{R}$, which is what an off-the-shelf MILP solver supports.

Comment: I'm missing something here. The constraint $f(x)$ true here becomes $Ax=1,$ right? Why do we need $y$ Doesn't its presence turn XOR to OR?

Comment: @prubin The $Ax=1$ is really $Ax\equiv 1\mod 2$. We want each sum to be odd.

Comment: My bad. I thought the multiple input version of XOR meant exactly one input must be 1, but Wikipedia agrees with you.

Comment: CP-SAT supports both xor and floating point coefficients